# HTML columns not rendering with DocuSign API

Tags: html, rendering, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign sandbox(test) environment to send HTML documents for digital signature.

As i understand it, Docusign converts all document types to PDF. This process seems to be causing rendering issues for my HTML document, specifically for column structures. I've tried using "Float", "Inline-Block", and "Flex" for displaying columns and all fail to get rendered properly by DocuSign.

Here is what the HTML looks like BEFORE going through DocuSign This is using Flex to create the two 'columns':
[image]

And here is what the HTML looks like AFTER going through DocuSign. Notice the columns are gone. 
[image]

EDIT: Here is the HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<style>
#wrapper{
 display: flex;
}
#contact-left{
 flex: 1;

}
#contact-right{
 flex: 1

}
.anchor-tags{
 color:white
}
</style>
<title>Docusign Template</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

 <div id="contact-left">
  <h3>Date:</h3>
  <h3>Contact Name:</h3>
  <h3>Firm Name: ("Broker")</h3><span class="anchor-tags">franklinrepsig</span>
  <h3>Lender: ("Assignor")</h3>
 </div>
 <div id="contact-right">
  <h3>Phone No:</h3>
  <h3>Fax No:</h3>
  <h3>Date: </h3><span class="anchor-tags">assigneedate</span>
 </div>

 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I've added HTML code

Comment: Have you tried html tables?

Comment: I have not tried HTML tables. How would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using HTML tables is rendering the document correctly. Please try the following

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <style>
        .anchor-tags {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Docusign Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="35%"><h3>Date:</h3></td>
            <td width="35%"></td>
            <td width="15%"><h3>Phone No:</h3></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Contact Name:</h3></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><h3>Fax No:</h3></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Firm Name: ("Broker")</h3></td>
            <td><span class="anchor-tags">franklinrepsig</span></td>
            <td><h3>Date: </h3></td>
            <td><span class="anchor-tags">assigneedate</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Lender: ("Assignor")</h3></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what I would recommend